# Comparing stability of 2-propenyl cation and 1-propyl cation

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, hybridization

> Compare the stability of 2-propenyl cation and 1-propyl cation:
>
> $$\underset{\text{2-propenyl cation}}{\ce{CH2=CH-CH2+}}\qquad \underset{\text{1-propyl cation}}{\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2+}}$$

In 2-propenyl cation we get resonance. So, 2-propenyl cation seems to be more stable, but due to the double bond (or, more precisely, the $\mathrm{sp}^2$ carbon) in 2-propenyl cation, an electronegative carbon atom which makes cation less stable.

In case of 1-propyl cation due to inductive effect cation is getting stabilized, but we know resonance is more stabilising than inductive effect.

I would answer that 1-propyl cation is more stable than 2-propenyl cation because we get $\mathrm{sp}^2$ or a more electronegative C in 2-propenyl cation making it less stable.

I'm really confused which factor is more effective: stability of resonance or destabilisation due to the $\mathrm{sp}^2$-hybridized carbon in 2-propenyl cation.
What would be a valid zero-order approximation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stability order -  $2$-propenyl cation>$1$-Propyl cation

Resonance has way more effect on the cation than that tiny-whiny little weak $\mathrm {sp}^2$ hybridised carbon

Comment: Electronic configurations are to be written upright, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) for a list of what should be upright and what shouldn't..

Comment: @OscarLanzi Dear Sir, i'm at very initial stage of learning organic Chem. We haven't covered whole IUPAC in our school but i saw a similar question on chegg(link provided below) according to them it's name is 2-propenyl cation. If i'm wrong please correct me it will help me alot in future. Thanks,

Comment: @OscarLanzi link of question -   https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/2-propenyl-cation-appears-primary-carbocation-yet-considerab-chapter-6-problem-49p-solution-9781133952848-exc